# pdf extract to docx with unicode characters C#

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, docx, itext7

I'm using the itext7 library to convert pdf file to Docx, the file includes Vietnamese text (type Unicode/utf8 ), some parts of it were converted correctly but some were not. Example: "DÇu th¶o méc (L¹c, võng, c¸m...)" stand for "Dầu thảo mộc( lạc, vừng, cám)". So how can I handle this problem? Do I need include some fonts?

Comment: Quite often the issue is a problem in the PDF in question. Thus, please share the test PDF for analysis.

Comment: As well as the code you are using

Comment: Good test - if you open this PDF file and you copy and paste the text into a Word document, is it correct then? If not, you're likely looking at a PDF file error, not an iText problem.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche oh, I coppied to the word text and it's not correct too, so I think my pdf file has problem. I manually replaced the weird characters, it took a morning though :(